# Is it possible to use Spring Webclient to post files to an endpoint expecting application/json without reading the files into memory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

I'm trying to POST to an endpoint that looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint", consumes="application/json")
public ResponsePojo post(final @RequestBody UploadPojo uploadPojo) {
    ...
}
```

Where the request body looks like this:

```
public class UploadPojo {
    private String metadata;
    private List<InnerClass>;
}

public class InnerClass {
    private String metadata;
    private byte[] data;
}
```

My current code to achieve this is using Spring `WebClient`, and it looks something like this:

```
//Create the base webClient
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
    .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        ...
    })
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
    .build();
    
//Perform the upload
webClient.post()
    .uri("endpoint")
    .body(Mono.just(UploadPojo), UploadPojo.class)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ResponsePojo.class);
```

The issue really comes in because to call the above code I need to have an UploadPojo, which means I need to load the upload file contents into its internal byte[] in memory, which is not only feels like a slow extra step but also can cause JVM memory issues with larger uploads.

If I'm unable to change the endpoint, are there any possible changes I could make to avoid reading the file contents into byte[] memory?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid creating JVM memory issues while uploading large files, you can use the **streaming method** rather than reading the file directly into memory.

To follow this approach you have to use the `Flux.fromStream` operation to create a flux of ByteBuffer object from `InputSteam` which will read the uploaded file.

With this approach, you can *(let's say)* "split" the file into small pieces instead of loading the whole file into JVM's memory.

Here is an example of reading the file into a flux:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
    .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        ...
    })
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
    .build();

// read the uploading file into Flux
Flux < ByteBuffer > fileContent = Flux.fromStream(() -> new FileInputStream(uploadFile))
    .map(buf -> ByteBuffer.wrap(buf))
    .doOnTerminate(() -> fileInputStream.close());

// use the flux for uploadPojo
UploadPojo uploadPojo = new UploadPojo();
uploadPojo.setMetadata(fileMetadata);
uploadPojo.setData(fileContent);

webClient.post()
    .uri("endpoint")
    .body(Mono.just(uploadPojo), UploadPojo.class)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ResponsePojo.class);
```

I would suggest reading about [WebFlux](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux) before going with this method. Since it has its [drawbacks](https://blog.pragmatists.com/unobvious-traps-of-spring-webflux-16924a0d76d5). For example, it is way slower than just simply reading the entire file in JVM's memory.